# Java Search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, search

Can any one tell the java example/algorithm to search element in an array with following implementation:
    - O(n^2) algorithm and 
    - O(n) algorithm

Note: This is not a homework.

Comment: how about Arrays.binarySearch from the API  ???

Comment: O(n²) should be easy; take the length, call it n, wait for n² seconds, then do a linear search.

Comment: @Iarsmans, I think he's looking for -O(n^2) and -O(n) algorithms (minus sign before big O)

Comment: When its not a homework, please explain the reason for searchin a O(n²) algorithm - as noted, it doesn't make sense for a trivial search. (and you can search better than O(n) in sorted arrays, as stated by @chaitanya10

Comment: @DThought: Exactly my thoughts. I cannot imagine a reason why someone searches an O(n^2) algorithm without homework....-1 for question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Searching for a single item in an array is `O(N)`
- Searching for a longest run of increasing numbers in an array is `O(N^2)` if you use a straightforward algorithm with two nested loops<sup>*</sup>

Note: This is *not* Java-specific.

---

<sup>*</sup> A faster algorithm exists to do this search.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to do a `O(n²)` search algorithm.

To do a `O(n)` algorithm just search the element in the list.

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
  if(array[i]==search)
    return array[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `O(n)` would be just a linear search; traverse the list from start to end until you encounter whatever it is you're searching for.

It's strange that you want an `O(n²)` algorithm... but what you could do is, in each iteration of your for-loop (in the `O(n)` search), sleep for a duration defined by the length of the array (`Thread.sleep(array.length)`). The 'sleeping' period would be `O(n)` as it depends linearly on the length of the array, and the overall linear search would also be `O(n)`, so in conjunction the entire process would be `O(n²)`.

---

***`O(n)`***

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
    if (array[i] == SOME_ELEMENT) {
        // ...
        break;
    }
 }
```

***`O(n²)`***

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
    Thread.sleep(array.length);
    if (array[i] == SOME_ELEMENT) {
        // ...
        break;
    }
 }
```